# PHP - is there a easy way to change from Smarty to TWIG templating system?

Tags: php, smarty, twig

I am just wondering if there is a easy way to change over from smarty to Twig templating system, without a risk, and without editing manually one by one (because my site has over 1000+ templates files and i cannot re-write one by one) on the other hand ,

reason why i want to change over is

1. Twig performs better in memory and cpu time 
   (see http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php  )
2. smarty is now becoming very inactive and not the best template system around ...
3. In smarty is in-ability use with modern frameworks like symfony ...etc

I found one converter

```
https://github.com/freshrichard/smartytotwig
```

however i don't the the accuracy of the template conversion on this one ..

any other ideas on what should i do ?

Answer (score 5):

It's an old question, but if someone has the same problem this could help.

I used [toTwig](https://github.com/turbophp/to-twig) to convert Smarty templates to Twig templates. Converted without an error.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard about any transitional tools, most likely you will have to update manually.

About performance, I would say it depends. Due to my tests - Smarty performs better. I like Twig, but as i can see on large nested arrays with lots of conditions - it is really slow.

Try [Fenom](https://github.com/bzick/fenom), it is incredibly fast and nearly compatible with Smarty.

Comment: Well, these days the performance argument doesn't seem to be valid anymore. There is a benchmarking tool which says the opposite: https://github.com/dominics/smarty-twig-benchmark - I ran it for my self a couple of times and twig was about 50-60% faster.